# remove all special characters and replace space javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to remove all special characters and replace space with '-'

**e.g** const str = "SanDisk SSD PLUS 1TB Internal SSD SATA III 6 Gb/s"
i want this as an answer // "SanDisk-SSD-PLUS-1TB-Internal-SSD-SATA-III-6-Gbs"

Comment: And where exactly are you stumbling with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to achieve it

`replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")` is to remove all special characters but keep space characters

`replace(/ /g, "-")` is to replace all space characters with `-`

```js
const str = "SanDisk SSD PLUS 1TB Internal SSD SATA III 6 Gb/s";
const result = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "").replace(/ /g, "-")
console.log(result);
```